# Can HP Virtual Connect modules be used as a layer 2 switch?

Tags: networking, hp

I have an HP C7000 enclosure which I recently upgraded with a pair of HP Flex-10 Virtual Connect Ethernet modules (HP PN: 455880-B21).

Each module has 16 downlink ports to connect to server blades via the midplane and 8 uplink ports to connect to other network switches. I'd like to know if it's possible to directly cable other servers to the uplink ports on the VC ENet modules and if so, how do I accomplish this? I've tried creating additional ethernet networks within the virtual connect UI but I can't get any packets to flow to/from the server plugged into those ports.

Essentially I want to treat the VC modules as layer 2 switches.

Comment: Any special reason why you want this?

Comment: I don't have a normal switch capable of 10Gbit operation. This is for a lab environment.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is essentially the default configuration of a VC.

All you need to do is create one 'ethernet network', allow it to handle VLANs, set it's default speeds to 10Gbps, add in uplinks and then create server profiles linking each server's pNIC 0 and 1, at 10Gbps, to that 'ethernet network' - voila! a L2 switch with a pair of uplinks to connect to any other servers or switches.

It's that simple.

Comment: can it be used to switch between uplinks? for example I want to connect some standalone servers to some of my blades using L2 so the VC ethernet module needs to be able to provide a L2 switch so that those servers can also talk to eachother. When I try such config (I add one uplinkport for each of the server to my network) one of the uplink ports is set to Standby.